# Porting of C++ code with specialized templates to C language

Tags: c++, performance, templates, refactoring, c99

I have many very similar functions like

```
void someLargeFulction1(args)
{
    IDENTICAL CODE
    DIFFERENT CODE 1
    IDENTICAL CODE
}

//---------------------------//
//---------------------------//

void someLargeFulctionN(args)
{
    IDENTICAL CODE
    DIFFERENT CODE N
    IDENTICAL CODE
}
```

All these functions differs only in  `DIFFERENT CODE N` part (this is a shot series of floating point operations). Since most of the `someLargeFulctionN` codes is identical, I wont to avoid code replication because this greatly complicates code maintenance. Reducing reps is my  major goal. Unfortunately, I can not organize `DIFFERENT CODE` as function call and pass this functions as a `someLargeFulction` argument due to critical performance impact -  `DIFFERENT CODE` performed much faster than a typical function call, excluding the case of  call inlining by compiler. I would not like to organize `someLargeFulctionN` as macro definition (which however is the possible solution).

In the C++ programming language I have very simple and useful solution - template functions. I can do something like:

```
template <int N>
void someLargeFulction(args)
{
    IDENTICAL CODE
    differentCode<N>();
    IDENTICAL CODE
 }
```

And specialize differentCode() function for all variants. For all tested compilers (g++, MVSC) it works great! The compiler always inlines a `differentCode` call and I have the necessary number of `someLargeFulction` variants. The problem is that now I need to port this code to С98. For solve the problem directly, I need to create a full number of `someLargeFulction` copies, this is a bad decision. Using a macro-definition with `someLargeFulction` implementation  acceptable, but not desirable. What other options do you see?

Comment: I don't think your example really demonstrates the points you've listed, but nothing you've shown can't be done with function pointers.

Comment: _"c++ templates usage allows not only to reduce the amount of code"_:  be aware that "amount of code" here refers to "amout of code to by typed by the programmer" and not to "amout of code generated by the compiler".

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense.  "What features from using a socket wrench can I take advantage of with my hammer?"

Comment: Have you tried the equivalent C code using function pointers? If so, you will have noted that at full optimization there isn't actually any indirect calling going on.

Comment: @DmytroDadyka In your switch you pass the function pointer you want applied. All of your operations share a common signature. You could also use macros for this since, as you've said, you have little interest in the binary size, you just don't want to write repetitive code. There are features of templates that you would have trouble emulating in C, but this example isn't one of them.

Comment: A C macro would make the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define doIt(OP,a,b) do##OP(a,b)

#define performTmpl(OP,a,b,c) { for (int i=0; i<10; i++) a[i]=doIt(OP,b[i],c[i]); }

enum { ADD, SUB };

int doADD(int a,int b) { return a+b; }
int doSUB(int a,int b) { return a-b; }

int main() {
        printf("%d\n",doIt(ADD,5,4));
        printf("%d\n",doIt(SUB,5,4));

        int x[10], y[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, z[10]={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
        performTmpl(ADD,x,y,z);
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) printf("%d\n",x[i]);
}
```

Comment: the "great" `performTmpl` is very easy to write as a define (see edit). (1) is verified, (2) no call either, (3) obviously as you already made it